# Hello I am using a Collection View cell and I want to record how many of them are clicked "made true" and return on the next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

In this Detail View controller I have a label that tells you how many items you have added to your cart, I want to take the number of items clicked on in my collection view controller and return that value into my label on the detail view controller. In my collection view controller the collection view cells are clicked and their corresponding bool value is changed and then I want only the ones that have been changed to be counted and passed through using string interpolation to update the number of items chosen for the cart.

```
import UIKit


class ShoppingListDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var shoppingItemController: ShoppingItemController?
    var itemsInCart = 0
    var shoppingItem: ShoppingItem?
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfItemsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userAddressTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var submitOrderButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func tappedSubmitOrder(_ sender: Any) {
        showAlert()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func showAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Order Successful!!!", message: "\(userNameTextField.text ?? " ") your order will be delivered to \(userAddressTextField.text ?? " ")in 15 mins", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if shoppingItem?.added.self == false {
            itemsInCart += 1
            numberOfItemsLabel.text = "You currently have \(itemsInCart) items(s) in your shopping list"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:
Ok, you just replace in the `ShoppingListDetailViewController.viewWillAppear(_:)` function.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)

  guard let shoppingItemController = shoppingItemController else { return }
  var chosenItems: [ShoppingItem] = []
  for item in shoppingItemController.shoppingItems { 
    if item.added {
      chosenItems.append(item)
    }
  }

  numberOfItemsLabel.text = "You currently have \(chosenItems.count) items(s) in your shopping list"
}
```

And on `ShoppingListCollectionViewController.swift`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ShoppingItemCollectionViewCell
  /* here you do just changed new declare chosenItem.added, not shoppingItemController.shoppingItems 
  var chosenItem = shoppingItemController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item]
  chosenItem.added.toggle()
  */ 
  // so you just use this to change shoppingItem's status be added
  shoppingItemController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item].added.toggle()

  cell.hasBeenAddedLabel.text = chosenItem.added ? "Added" : "Not Added"
  print(chosenItem.added)
}
```

And old answer were unused, you can remove it all and modify it to updated answer.

old answer:
I think .. maybe you just want when cell be selected the ShoppingListDetailVC.itemsInCart will increase of one.

If I'm not think wrong, you can use variable didSet{}

```
// In ShoppingListDetailViewController.swift
var itemInCart: Int = 0 { 
  didSet { 
    numberOfItemsLabel.text = "You currently have \(itemsInCart) items(s) in your shopping list"
  }
}
```

And on your collectionViewController, maybe you declared a variable for ShoppingListDetailViewController
Here I suppose its name `shopListDetailVC`

```
// when cell be selected, you add something here. 
func onSelectedAddCart() { 
   shopListDetailVC.itemsInCart += 1
}
```

Or Maybe you needn't itemsInCart, just replace variable of the shoppingItem to

```
var shoppingItems: [ShoppingItem] = [] { 
  didSet { 
    numberOfItemsLabel.text = "You currently have \(shoppingItems.count) items(s) in your shopping list"
  }
}
```

Then when cell be selected will be

```
func onSelectedAddCart(with item: ShoppingItem) { 
   shopListDetailVC.shoppingItems.append(item)
}
```

Final, if your ShoppingListDetailViewController was not declare in collectionViewController, then try to pass the shopListDetailVC or use others way(e.g. use protocol or closure) to pass the events that when your item be selected.

Comment: Is this three different solutions? I am sorry I am only 3 weeks into learning swift and I don't think I understand the solution, after I create this function assuming I put it in the right place where do I call it? as of now it still says all items are in cart

Comment: Maybe you can show me what you do when cell beSelected.
I need more informations to know your collectionViewController and who was the super of `ShoppingListViewController`, how you displayed it.

Comment: https://github.com/RichGibbs-prog/ios-sprint-challenge-shopping-list

Comment: Thank you very much this worked wonders! Now I must try and save it using basic persistence.

Comment: It's great. Let's enjoy Swift!